# What is the major hydrolysis product of 2,2,2-trifluoroethyl 2-acetamido-3-phenylprop-2-enoate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, hydrolysis, esters

In the below reaction we have to find the major hydrolysis product of 2,2,2-trifluoroethyl 2-acetamido-3-phenylprop-2-enoate.

[image]

My doubt is why the major hydrolysis is not when $\ce{OH-}$ at the $\ce{C}$ of $\ce{CF3}$ as it is more electropostive. However the major product is given by the following reaction, why?

[image]

Comment: That's a not a hydrolysis product. Are you just asking for the "hydrolysis product" because of the reaction conditions?

Comment: @Zhe which one is not hydrolysis product . The one which I thought or the other one

Comment: The other one. How is that hydrolysis?

Comment: Also, C-F bonds are notoriously hard to hydrolyze. You should have supposed that hydrolysis would simply break the ester, that would be at least logical.

Comment: @IvanNeretin why it is hard to hydrolyse

Answer (score 3):

Plain hydrolysis would just replace trifluorexthoxide with hydroxide.

But you might want to consider that your staring material in equilibrium with another tautomer:

[image: tautomerism]

Deprotonation of the $\ce{OH}$ in the right structure, followed by an intramolecular reaction (transesterification/lactonization) in which $\ce{CF3CH2O-}$ is kicked out should give rise to an oxazolone.

Comment: How can we know which reaction can produce major product

Comment: Does the second reaction is also hydrolysis

Comment: @J.Doe Hydrolysis is an extremely broad term. I'd rather call this a cyclization, which is still broad but describes the outcome of the reaction much better. On a second look, this looks a bit an intramolecular variant of the *Erlenmeyer-Plöchl* reaction.

Comment: That reaction is not hydrolysis, it's a transesterification.

Comment: @Variax Yes, just as I wrote in my answer ;)